# How to get sane margin sizes suitable for paperback books using memoir?

Tags: margins, memoir, paper-size, book-design

I'm trying to make a document suitable for printing as a trade paperback. For that reason I'm using the `memoir` class using `statementpaper` which sets the page size to 5.5" x 8.5".

Here's the basic structure I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,statementpaper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for sample text

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

which produces the following pages:

[image: sample]

As you can see, the margins are *huge*.

How can I get margin sizes that are more appropriate for paperback books of this size?

Comment: By setting them directly.  What is "sane" though? I suppose I could go measure a bunch of book dimensions from my own collection, I'd rather hear it from you.

Comment: I don't know, I just know that no book I own has margins this huge. I assumed there were at least *some* standard sizes?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, me neither. Perhaps a search [like this](http://tinyurl.com/ozbdqmv) would be helpful.

Comment: Once you have found the margins you like, you can set them using memoirs build in interface, no need to include the geometry package

Comment: Can you elaborate @daleif? Maybe post it in an answer?

Comment: It is all in in the manual. The fastest is to look up, `\setlrmarginsandblock`, the equivalent with ul instead of lr and don't forget the vital `\checkandfixthelayout `

Comment: Thanks @daleif I've posted a new answer using this recommendation.

Comment: Since you're using `memoir` (jolly good!), you should *ignore any advice to use `geometry`*; memoir has excellent built-in facilities to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer as noted by @daleif is to use `memoir`'s built in margin functions:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{inner}{outer}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{top}{bottom}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Using margin sizes measured from a 5.5" x 8.5" book printed in 1884:

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.00in}{0.625in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Comment: Not *the* answer. Remember, memoir has *two* ways of setting the layout: specifying the margins and thus the text block or specifying the text block and placing that on the paper, thereby defining the margins. The first is probably easier to understand

Comment: @daleif What are the benefits of the second technique?

Comment: Depends. Sometimes you are just told that the text should be (around) A x B in size. That calculation becomes tedious to make if you are specifying the text block by setting the margins. So it all depends on the requirements you have. For the most part I use the first one. Do remember that memoir does a height check such that the generated text height match an integral number of lines.

Comment: @daleif Then it sounds like given the question's requirements, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per @ArtemMavrim's recommendation to look at the `geometry` package's documentation, this is how you set four different margins:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=(inside),rmargin=(outside),tmargin=(top),bmargin=(bottom)]]{geometry}
```

Using margin recommendations from [this random website](http://www.balboapress.com/FAQ/Manuscript.aspx) for a 5.5" x 8.5" book:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=0.125in,rmargin=0.5in,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
```

Or if you prefer, here are the margin sizes of a random book printed in 1884:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=0.75in,rmargin=0.75in,tmargin=1.00in,bmargin=0.625in]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 1):

The margins you object to are the result of literally hundreds of years of experimentation by professional typesetters. Don't mess with them unless you know what you are doing. And if you know what you are doing, you won't mess with them. If you insist, you should first read up on page layout and margins. Also consider that over-long lines (more than some 80 characters, tops) are hard to read.

The memoir class has a few suggested margins, e.g. `\semiisopage` sets narrower margins.

Comment: In theory your warning about not neglecting years of experimentation by professional typesetters sounds legitimate, but when comparing memoir's default margin sizes to actual books that I own in the given size, they are so different that it seems memoir's defaults aren't being applied to a paper of this size automatically, hence going full circle to my question of how to enable such defaults. Either way, I'll look into your suggestion of using `\semiisopage` and friends.

Comment: After reading the documentation on this a bit, it's not clear which style is most appropriate for a published book. The closest thing to what books I actually own have is `\medievalpage[12]`, using `statementpaper` size (5.5" x 8.5").